# Python Glade - Reset a Grid

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, glade

He everyone!
I'am creating a Grid-Layout in Glade and adding some Labels and buttons. THe User can add more rows by a little pop-up menue. After that the data is reloading and all labels and buttons will re-write on the grid. It works fine but the problem is, that the labels, which are still on the grid, are still there so the text will over-laying. Now i want to remove all existing labels from the grid to start re-writing with a empty grid. Set-Parent, remove or something like that doesnt works - main problem is that a dont get some data back from the grid...some ideas? THX!

Comment: So you want to remove all children from the GtkGrid? Or just the GtkLabels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all the child widgets:

```
for child in grid.get_children():
    grid.remove(child)
```

To remove only the labels, add an extra `if` statement in there.

Comment: YEAH! It works - thank u so much! I tried it with childrens, but a always get null - wrong logic. THX!